# Enter BIOS to Load Ubuntu from inside Windows instead?

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, uefi

Had a working dual boot machine,

Windows is on a 960 Evo (NVME) so loads extremely quickly.
Ubuntu is on a Intel SATA III SSD (SSDSC2BP480G410)

Worked fine but has been a while since I fired up Ubuntu. Since I've made some changes to accommodate work from home, and now run peripherals (including keyboard) through an inexpensive USB switch. Reading what others have said elsewhere and it seems like some report that BIOS doesn't pickup the keyboard quick enough and it fires straight into windows (despite hitting delete/F2) on my Asus Z370-A (8700k).

In order to even interrupt and get into BIOS I had to connect keyboard (Durgod K320 TKL) directly to my computer. I changed the setting for timing, but oddly it would still just show the Asus logo then go directly into booting windows. Not even sure now if I can get into the Linux drive. Any suggestions as to how to manage the dual-boot with a keyboard that is through a USB switch (connects to surface dock, entirely separate machine). Sorry if this is in the wrong place, not sure where else it would go.

Comment: F2 is typically UEFI settings, but f12, f8 or f12 typically UEFI boot selections. In UEFI do you have full USB support on? Are both systems UEFI or both old BIOS installs? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you oldfred, was a silly mistake on my end. I had totally forgotten the F8 to select boot. Turns out the install is fine and well. Unfortunately trying via the USB switch didnt work but used an old keyboard direct to a case usb and it let me use it. Guess thats a trade-off of the switch is having to keep a spare keyboard laying around. Thanks for tips on repairing boot, will keep for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always buy a second keyboard from a supermarket, they are cheap enough. Plug that directly into the main computer's USB socket and use that to  get into the BIOS. I've tested on my machine and with two keyboards, I can start typing a word or sentence on one keyboard and switch to the other to finish, without any problem.

Comment: Thanks looks like that will have to be the route on this one.